# How to sort discord channels in a custom order?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a list of channel names like this:

```py
{
  'Information': [
    'rules', 
    'about', 
    'announcements', 
    'community-updates'
    ],
  'Moderation': [
    'mod-commands', 
    'isolation'
    ],
  'Interface': [
    'election-feed',
    'debate-feed',
    'commands'
    ], 
  'Events': [], 
  'Community': [
    'general',
    'memes'
    ], 
  'Debate': [
    'Debate 1',
    'Debate 2'
    ],
  'Logs': [
    'voice'
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to re-arrange channels to be in this format on running a command using discord.py using `await channel.edit(position=position)`. I already have a `get_channel()` function which retrieves the correct channel object from the name. How do I do this? Discord's sorting is very confusing and won't allow regular sequential ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is the solution:

```py
# Reorder Channels
for category_name in CHANNEL_SORT_ORDER.keys():
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=category_name)
    position = list(CHANNEL_SORT_ORDER.keys()).index(category_name)
    await category.edit(position=position)

for category_name in CHANNEL_SORT_ORDER.keys():
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=category_name)
    sorted_channels = []
    for channel_name in CHANNEL_SORT_ORDER[category_name]:
        channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=channel_name)
        sorted_channels.append(channel)

    if sorted_channels:
        min_position = min(sorted_channels, key=lambda c: c.position)
        for new_position, channel in enumerate(sorted_channels, start=min_position.position):
            await channel.edit(category=category, position=new_position)
```